# Smooth every group via `do`

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some data, a sample of which below. My goal is to apply a `gam` to each Year, and to have another value that is the predicted value from gam model.

```
fertility <- structure(list(AGE = c(15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L
), Year = c(1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 
1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 
1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1931, 
1931, 1931, 1931, 1931, 1931, 1931, 1931, 1931, 1931, 1931, 1931, 
1931, 1931, 1931, 1931, 1931, 1931, 1931, 1931, 1931, 1931, 1931, 
1931, 1931, 1931, 1931, 1931, 1931, 1931), fertility = c(5.170284269, 
14.18135114, 27.69795144, 44.61216712, 59.08896308, 89.66036496, 
105.4563852, 120.1754041, 137.4074262, 148.7159407, 161.5645606, 
157.200515, 143.6340251, 127.8855125, 117.7343628, 159.2909484, 
126.6158821, 109.0681613, 86.98223678, 70.64470361, 111.0070633, 
86.15051988, 68.9204159, 55.92722274, 42.93402958, 56.84376018, 
39.35337243, 26.72142573, 18.46207596, 9.231037978, 4.769704534, 
13.08261815, 25.55198857, 41.15573626, 54.51090896, 81.99522459, 
96.44082973, 109.9015072, 125.6603492, 136.0020892, 148.679958, 
144.6639404, 132.1793638, 117.6867783, 108.345172, 144.2820726, 
114.68575, 98.79142865, 78.7865069, 63.9883456, 100.217918, 77.77726461, 
62.22181169, 50.49147014, 38.76112859, 52.48807067, 36.33789508, 
24.67387938, 17.04740757, 8.523703784)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -60L), .Names = c("AGE", 
"Year", "fertility"))
```

So, the non-dplyr, "dumb" way to do it would be

```
count <- 0
for (i in 1930:1931){
  count <- count + 1
  temp <- filter(fertility, Year == i)
  mod <- mgcv::gam(fertility ~ s(AGE), data=temp)
  pred[length(15:44) * (count - 1) + 1:30] <- predict(mod, newdata = data.frame(AGE = 15:44))
}

fertility1 <- mutate(fertility, pred = pred)
```

But I'd like a method in `dplyr`. My thought was to use `do` to create a model for each column, then use `predict` to obtain the values. The first step I can do, but I'm struggling to implement the second part in `dplyr`:

```
library(mgcv)
library(dplyr)

  fertility %>%
    #filter(!is.na(fertility)) %>%  # not sure if this is necessary
    group_by(Year) %>%
    dplyr::do(model = mgcv::gam(fertility ~ s(AGE), data = .)) %>%
    left_join(fertility, .) %>%
    mutate(smoothed = predict(model, newdata = AGE))
```

I get the error message

```
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "list"
```

which presumably means `dplyr` doesn't remember that `model` is a model, rather than just a list element.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The **smart** way to do this would be to use factor-smooth interactions that have been available in **mgcv** for ages, either via `by` terms in `s()` or via the newer `bs = "fs"` basis type. Here is an example with your data:

```
library("mgcv")
## Make Year a factor
fertility <- transform(fertility, Year = factor(Year))
## Fit model using by terms - include factor as fixed effect too!
mod <- gam(fertility ~ Year + s(AGE, by = Year), data = fertility)
## Plot to see what form this model takes
plot(mod, pages = 1)
```

[image]

```
## Some prediction data
ages <- with(fertility, seq(min(AGE), max(AGE)))
## Need to replicate this once per Year
pdat <- with(fertility,
             data.frame(AGE = rep(ages, nlevels(Year)),
                        Year = rep(levels(Year), each = length(ages))))
## Add the fitted values to the prediction data
pdat <- transform(pdat, fitted = predict(mod, newdata = pdat))
head(pdat)

> head(pdat)
  AGE Year     fitted
1  15 1930 -0.8496705
2  16 1930 15.9568574
3  17 1930 33.0754019
4  18 1930 50.7419122
5  19 1930 68.9116594
6  20 1930 87.1306489
```

However, you can just ask for the fitted values if all you want to do is predict for the observed values of `AGES`:

```
fertility <- transform(fertility, fitted = predict(mod))
head(fertility)

> head(fertility)
  AGE Year fertility     fitted
1  15 1930  5.170284 -0.8496705
2  16 1930 14.181351 15.9568574
3  17 1930 27.697951 33.0754019
4  18 1930 44.612167 50.7419122
5  19 1930 59.088963 68.9116594
6  20 1930 89.660365 87.1306489
```

You might also look at the specific factor-smooth basis type `bs = "fs"` and `?smooth.terms` and `?factor.smooth.interaction` for details; basically these are efficient if you have a lot of levels but you want each level's smoother to have the same value of the smoothing parameter.

The main advantage here is that you use all your data and fit a single model, which you can then interrogate in a number of ways not easily open to you if you fit *m* separate models, such as being able to investigate differences in the smoothers per year.

Comment: It might be worth emphasizing that this uses a different (better) model than the OP's, in case someone notices a discrepancy in the results of this answer vs the others.

Answer (score 3):

The non-dplyr, "smart" way to do it would be

```
do.call(rbind,
        lapply(split(fertility, fertility$Year), function(df) {
            df$pred <- predict(gam(fertility ~ s(AGE), data=df))
            df
        }))
```

See `?do.call`, `?lapply` and `?split`.

Or, if you don't like nested function calls:

```
fertility %>%
   split(fertility$Year) %>%
   lapply(function(df) {
       df$pred <- predict(gam(fertility ~ s(AGE), data=df))
       df
   }) %>%
   do.call(rbind, .)
```

Comment: You have too many closing `)` in `do.call()` (non-dplyr solution). And your `dplyr` solution doesn't work for me (Error in split.default(x = seq_len(nrow(x)), f = f, drop = drop, ...) : group length is 0 but data length > 0)

Comment: @Pascal You can simply edit the parenthesis out yourself. Yeah, the dplyr bit is not valid `dplyr`-ish.

Comment: The *really* smart way would be to use `mgcv::gam()` to its fullest and fit a single model using factor-smooth interactions ;-) (Sorry, couldn't resist after I noticed we'd both used "smart" in the opening words of our respective answers)

Comment: Oh, I see, magrittr then? Not sure why you're being cryptic; you want me to guess what package your second block of code is using? It is easy to mistake it for dplyr (as Pascal also did) since, you know, you make no mention of using a package, and magrittr is very rarely used on SO relative to dplyr. With magrittr loaded, it does run fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

**keep the original data.frame in the `do` results,** as suggested by @Henrik:

```
df %>%
   group_by(Year) %>%
   do(data.frame(.,pred = predict(gam(fertility ~ s(AGE), data=.))))
```

---

**Add `data.table` to the chain.**

```
require(data.table)
df %>%
   data.table     %>%
   group_by(Year) %>%
   mutate(pred = predict(gam(fertility ~ s(AGE))))
```

The failure of `mutate` without the `data.table` line may have something to do with recent changes in `gam`'s scoping, [mentioned briefly by @GavinSimpson in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/23412758#23412758).

Comment: Do you really need `tidyr::unnest`? Wouldn't it be enough to wrap the stuff inside `do` with `data.frame`: `do(data.frame(pred = predict(gam(fertility ~ s(AGE), data=.))))`?

Comment: You can always refer to the data frame in the current group with `.`, just as you do (`.$blabla`; `data= .`), but there is no need to select each variable individually. Simply pick all of them by using the `.` only: `do(data.frame(., pred = predict(gam(fertility ~ s(AGE), data=.))))`

Comment: @Henrik Fixed. Okay, that syntax isn't so bad. It would be nicer if `mutate` just worked here, but I now suspect that isn't `dplyr`'s fault.

Answer (score 2):

Same result using:

```
predt=by(fertility[,-2],fertility[,2],function(z){
  mod=mgcv::gam(fertility ~ s(AGE), data=z)
  pred = predict(mod, newdata = data.frame(AGE = z$AGE))
  pred
})
fertility$pred = unlist(predt)
```